# How do I fix this error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)?

Tags: filezilla, lamp, ubuntu-16.04

I have created a Ubuntu 16.04 droplet on Digital Ocean and then implemented a LAMP framework. I have created a non-root user and have logged into the server with ssh. I have also logged into the server using sftp. However, I cannot transfer my files via the terminal as I 'do not have permission', even though I have given the non-root user the root permissions. So I thought I would try a client - Filezilla. When I try to connect to the server on here I receive the above error. Can anyone help me out please?

Here is a successful connection to an SSH server:

```
Status: Connecting to www.calumjamesflanagan.co.uk...
Status: Connected to www.calumjamesflanagan.co.uk
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Listing directory /root
Status: Directory listing of "/root" successful
```

Here is what my unsuccessful connection looks like:

```
Status: Connecting to 139.59.178.163...
Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
Command: open "calflan@139.59.178.163" 22
Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available 
(server sent: publickey)
Error: Could not connect to server
```

Comment: As I've already asked you on Stack Overflow, post verbose logs of successful connection using SSH and failed connection using SFTP.

Comment: Also what makes you think you will be able to copy files using FileZilla, if you cannot copy them using `sftp` command-line client?

Comment: Can you help me or not? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: As one of the answers pointed out you're connecting to a different server using FileZilla. The error means that server is expecting a public key authentication .

Answer (score 1):

For me `www.calumjamesflanagan.co.uk` resolves to `178.62.64.232`, not `139.59.178.163`.

It looks like you are connecting to a different server with FileZilla than you are with `ssh`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You asked me to show you a woking connection and then the one that is failing. The first output is a working server for `www.calumjamesflanagan.co.uk`, while the second output is me trying to connect to my other server (the one i could not write to).

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. So how could you get a "permissions denied" error from a server that you cannot even connect to?

Comment: In the question I state that when transferring files in Terminal (so I was connected to the server), I was told 'permission denied'. This has since been resolved by the answer I wrongly posted. Since I was told permission denied in terminal, I thought I would try to connect via FileZilla to see if there was any change. There I received the error that is in the main title of the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *"transferring files in Terminal (so I was connected to the server)"* is pretty vague, when you talk about two different servers, without telling us that you have two servers at all. Moreover *"transferring files in Terminal"* is unclear on its own.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED:

I had to change ownership on the directories on the remote server in order to write to them.

This was done using `sudo chown -R *UserName* \var\www\html`.

Comment: While this solves your original problem, it does not answer your question *"How do I fix this error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)?"*. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Stick to the topic.

Comment: Fair enough @MartinPrikryl . Should I add this to an edit of the question instead?